# Setting a font defined through \newfontfamily as main font

Tags: fonts, fontspec, fontfamily

I have a few specific font families that I'd like to reuse across different documents. Rather than copy-pasting the font definition in every document, I assumed I would do something like this in a shared e.g. `montserrat.sty` file:

```
\newfontfamily{\Montserrat}[
  Path=fonts/montserrat/,
  Extension = .ttf,
  Ligatures = TeX,
  UprightFont = *-Regular,
  BoldFont = *-Bold,
  ItalicFont = *-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
  FontFace={xl}{n}{*-ExtraLight},
  FontFace={xl}{it}{*-ExtraLightItalic},
  FontFace={l}{n}{*-Light},
  FontFace={l}{it}{*-LightItalic},
  FontFace={mb}{n}{*-Medium},
  FontFace={mb}{it}{*-MediumItalic},
  FontFace={k}{n}{*-Black},
  FontFace={k}{it}{*-BlackItalic},
]{Montserrat}
```

With this, I can use the font just fine in a Beamer theme:

```
\RequirePackage{montserrat}
\setbeamerfont{title}{family=\Montserrat, size={\fontsize{48}{48}}, series=\bfseries}
```

But I can't seem to figure out a way to use it as the main font of a regular text document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{montserrat}

\setmainfont{\Montserrat}
```

fails with `[fontspec] The font "\Montserrat " cannot be found`. I *could* duplicate the same arguments I passed to `newfontfamily` in my call to `setmainfont`, but that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid - I have a few different documents reusing a few different fonts.

Is there any way to set a font defined through `newfontfamily` as the main font of a document?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Incidentally, have you tried `\setmainfont{Montserrat}` instead of ``\setmainfont{\Montserrat}``?

Comment: `\setmainfont{Montserrat}` requires the font to be installed on the system, and ignores any previous `\newfontfamily` call - hence even if the font was installed on the system, I wouldn't necessarily have all the different weights and shapes defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the skeleton for your `montserrat.sty` file

```
\ProvidesPackage{montserrat}

\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\Montserrat}[
  NFSSFamily=Montserrat,% <--- the key
  %Path=fonts/montserrat/,% <--- I can only use the TeX Live ones
  Extension = .otf,% <--- I have OpenType fonts
  Ligatures = TeX,
  UprightFont = *-Regular,
  BoldFont = *-Bold,
  ItalicFont = *-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
  FontFace={xl}{n}{*-ExtraLight},
  FontFace={xl}{it}{*-ExtraLightItalic},
  FontFace={l}{n}{*-Light},
  FontFace={l}{it}{*-LightItalic},
  FontFace={mb}{n}{*-Medium},
  FontFace={mb}{it}{*-MediumItalic},
  FontFace={k}{n}{*-Black},
  FontFace={k}{it}{*-BlackItalic},
]{Montserrat}

\DeclareOption{default}{%
  \renewcommand{\familydefault}{Montserrat}%
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
```

Now a couple of test files.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[default]{montserrat}

\begin{document}

This is in Montserrat.

{\fontseries{mb}\selectfont Montserrat}

{\fontseries{k}\selectfont Montserrat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{montserrat}

\begin{document}

This is standard.

{\Montserrat
This is in Montserrat.

{\fontseries{mb}\selectfont Montserrat}

{\fontseries{k}\selectfont Montserrat}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want to add also

```
\DeclareOption{sfdefault}{%
  \renewcommand{\sfdefault}{Montserrat}%
}
```

so that `\usepackage[sfdefault]{montserrat}` will define Montserrat as the default sans serif font (like for `\setsansfont`).

With `beamer` you do `\usepackage{montserrat}` and the declaration you show in your post.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of renewing `familydefault`, that's exactly what I was after!

Answer (score 1):

If the [MontSerrat](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat) font has been downloaded and activated suitably on your system, and if you need just the four basic or default font weight/shape combinations -- upright, italic, bold, and bold-italic -- I can see no reason for not running

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{MontSerrat}
```

in the preamble.

Of course, if you want to use some of the non-default weight/shape combinations, you could replace `\setmainfont{MontSerrat}` with, say,

```
\setmainfont{MontSerrat}%
  [Path=/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/montserrat/,
   Extension=.otf,
   UprightFont=Montserrat-ExtraLight,
   ItalicFont=Montserrat-ExtraLightItalic,
   BoldFont=Montserrat-Black,
   BoldItalicFont=Montserrat-BlackItalic]
```

Comment: I'm using quite a lot of custom fonts that aren't available in a lot of systems, but do have stored in a repo next to my documents. I also use other weights and shapes, e.g. `Black`. I _could_ replace `\setmainfont{Montserrat}` with all the settings indeed, but that's exactly what I'd like to share instead - rather than defining those other weights and shapes over and over again in multiple documents.

Comment: @MarcPlano-Lesay - Is there something stopping you from creating a sty file that runs `\setmainfont{Montserrat}[<lots and lots of options>]` instead of `\newfontfamily{\Montserrat}[<lots and lots of options>]`? The question you posed in the title of your posting is -- unless I'm badly mistaken... -- if one can designate the `MontSerrat` font to be the main document font, via a suitable `\setmainfont` directive. The answer is an emphatic yes.